# Remove element from array where property is not present or null with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

having an array of element like this :

```
names = [
  {id: 1, name: "toto"},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3, name: "lala"}
]
```

i would like to remove elements where the value of name is null or not present or empty with typescript
i've tried:

```
names.filter(name => name.name !== null);
```

Comment: You can try like below  `names.filter(name => name.name);` //which will return properties which has name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no corresponsing property, name.name returns `undefined`, not `null`.

Use either of those:

`names.filter(name => name.name != null);`

`names.filter(name => name.name !== undefined);`

`names.filter(name => name.name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a check if the `name` property exists and is not null/undefined by checking `name.name`. See the following example.

```js
names = [
  {id: 1, name: "toto"},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3, name: "lala"}
];

console.log(names.filter(name => name.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
   {id:1,name:"toto"},
   {id:2},
   {id:3,name:"lala"}
]
    
data.filter(item => item.name)
```

result: [{id: 1, name: "toto"}, {id: 3, name: "lala"}]

Answer (score 1):

I think the most elegant solutoin is a filter loop. You can just copy-past the "filter" method

```
let names = [
{id:1,name:"toto"},
{id:2},
{id:3,name:"lala"}
];

let removedObject = names.filter(name => !name.name);
let newArrayWithOnlyNamedSubjects = names.filter(name => name.name);

console.log(removedObject);  // [{ id: 2 }]
console.log(newArrayWithOnlyNamedSubjects);  //[{id: 1, name: "toto"}, {id: 3, name: "lala"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for names which are valid:

```
names.filter(name => name.name);
```